# How to check if a field is blank and how to read the entered text?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

How to check whether a text field is blank i.e. no input is given if given how to store that text into a variable?

Comment: Please post something you tried and stuck with.

Answer (score 10):

Access **value** attribute of the `<input>` web element. Following is an example:

```
WebElement inputBox = driver.findElement(By.id("inputBoxId"));
String textInsideInputBox = inputBox.getAttribute("value");

// Check whether input field is blank
if(textInsideInputBox.isEmpty())
{
   System.out.println("Input field is empty");
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(by locator)); //find the text field

if (ele.getAttribute("value").isEmpty()) {
    //Do something if the text field is empty
}
else {
    //Store the value
    String store=ele.getAttribute("value");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var element = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id("your elements id"));
//store text
var text = element.getText();
//store value
var value = element.getAttribute("value");
//after that you can do anything you want with these variables.
```

Answer (score 0):

`wd.find_element_by_id('foo').get_attribute('value')`